# How to change the title of a report to be different from .rdl file name

Tags: ssrs-2016

What is the variable name that is being displayed in the web-portal as the report name?

Example: if my RDL file is named Reportforseeingthings.rdl

I want the name displayed in the web portal as "Report for seeing things"

Is there a report properties variable that can be modified before deployment to handle this along with a server config to grab that variable instead of the file name?

Open to other solutions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to do this. You can set the file name and description properties but the report name will always be the file name. You can modify it once deployed.

So options are potentially:

1. Just rename the file in the solution
2. Manually edit after deployment
3. Create linked reports with the desired name, redeploying will update the base report but the linked report name will stay the same.
4. Put the required title in the description and have a script that updates the names on demand or as part of a trigger or scheduled job.

something like

```
UPDATE r 
    SET Name  = Description 
    FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog r
    WHERE Name != Description and Description IS NOT NULL
```

Note that even doing this, the breadcrumb trail in the web portal will still show the original name, but the list/card views will show the name you want.